# How can i copy a Value of a certain Column if another column has "No" in it?

Tags: vba, ms-project

Very specific question. I got a task to learn vba, but i cant really find anything for my problem.

[screenshot of how it looks in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqP6n.png)

Basically if the column "Sammelvorgang" says "Nein", the Column "Text7" should contain the Value of "Nr." of that row

Im looking through the basics of VBA but i cant find a solution to target a specific column or a specific row.

```
Sub schedule_Number()

Dim tsk As Task

For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
    
    If Not (tsk Is Nothing) Then
    
        If (tsk.Sammelvorgang.Value = "Nein") Then
        
        tsk.Text7 = tsk.Nr
                    
        End If
        
    End If
    

Next tsk

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The code was posted correctly. The image was a screen shot of the user interface which was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the displayed value (always a string) and the stored value (date, string, number, etc). In VBA it is simpler to use the stored value. In this case Sammelvorgang is Summary (I believe) which is a boolean, so the code can be written as such:

```
Sub schedule_Number()

Dim tsk As Task
For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
    
    If Not (tsk Is Nothing) Then
        If Not tsk.Summary Then
            tsk.Text7 = tsk.ID
        End If
    End If
    
Next tsk
```

Unfortunately, in VBA the object names, properties, methods are all in English. It might be possible to use the [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/project.application.fieldnametofieldconstant) method of the Application object to derive the field ID from the native language field names. (I don't have any non-English versions to test this, however).

Then with the Field ID, the [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield) method can be used to return the *display* value (string).

---

Here is the English-language documentation: [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fieldnametofieldconstant) and [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield).